# geom_line() plot creates weird horizontally layered lines, second question on reducing axis ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2

Doing a very simple code in ggplot2 where I have a large df of two columns one showing dates and another percent.

```
#snippet of df this, goes on for 5,000+ rows

      date        percent
1     1997-04-15  0.78
2     1997-04-16  0.77
3     1997-04-17  0.77
4     1997-04-18  0.77
5     1997-04-21  0.77

# also the dput() of the df not sure if I did this right
structure(list(date = structure(c(9966, 9967, 9968, 9969, 9972, 
9973, 9974, 9975, 9976, 9979, 9980, 9981, 9982, 9983, 9986), class = "Date"), 
percent = c("0.78", "0.77", "0.77", "0.77", "0.77", "0.79", 
"0.79", "0.79", "0.79", "0.79", "0.79", "0.79", "0.79", "0.79", 
"0.79")), .Names = c("date", "percent"), row.names = c(NA,
```

15L), class = "data.frame")

Currently my `ggplot()` is something simple

```
ggplot( short_df, aes( date, percent ) ) + geom_line()
```

I try to plot a small snippet of the df to get a good idea of how the plot is going to look and I was greated by this:

[image]

When I do `geom_point()` the plot seems fine.

My second question is when plotting the entire df the plot seems to include every percent value:

[image: img]

I add `scale_y_discrete( breaks = pretty( DF$percent ) )` to the previous code and when I use the `short_df` the plot seems to split the ticks fine:

[image: img]

However, when I do it on the actual df it shows me a y axis with one tick:

[image: img]

I do get a warning:

> Warning message:
>   In pretty.default(BSD$percent) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: To make this [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), can you `dput` a representative sample of your data? My guess is that you have issues with types in your data (e.g. a factor column that should be numeric), and we'd need to see some of the actual data to know what's up

Comment: just to add an explanation to @camille 's request - don't dput your full data frame. E.g. use `dput(head(your_df, 15)) `  15 was just randomly chosen

Comment: like dput it into stack overflow or in the code sorry I don't follow. Update: just added it not sure if I did it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that "percent" is of type character:

```
str(short_df)

'data.frame':   15 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date   : Date, format: "1997-04-15" "1997-04-16" "1997-04-17" "1997-04-18" ...
 $ percent: chr  "0.78" "0.77" "0.77" "0.77" ...
```

As a result, **ggplot** treats "percent" as categorical, and does not connect lines between categories. Converting "percent" to numeric fixes the problem:

```
short_df$percent <- as.numeric(df$percent)

ggplot(short_df, aes( date, percent ) ) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Incidentally, the version of the plot that uses `geom_point()` is not correct. You can see that **ggplot** is plotting every unique value of "percent" (again, the behavior for character/categorical data types). With "percent" converted to numeric data, **ggplot** correctly calculates a series of well-spaced axis ticks.